# How to return different types based on std::is_same check

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following code:

```
template<typename T>
T foo() {
    if (std::is_same<T, int>::value)
        return 5;

    if (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
        return std::string("bar");

    throw std::exception();
}
```

When called with `foo<int>()`, it throws an error `cannot convert ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}’ to ‘int’ in return`.

I know the solution is to use template specialization, but I'm asking whether it is somehow possible to keep the current mechanism with checking the type via `std::is_same`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both branches of an `if` must be valid at compile-time, even if one of them is never executed.

If you have access to C++17, change the `if`s to `if constexpr`:

```
template<typename T>
T foo() {
    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, int>::value)
        return 5;

    if constexpr (std::is_same<T, std::string>::value)
        return std::string("bar");

    throw std::exception();
}
```

Before C++17, you will have to emulate this by using template specialisation:

```
template<typename T>
T foo()
{
    throw std::exception();
}

template <>
int foo<int>() {
    return 5;
}

template <>
std::string foo<std::string>() {
    return "bar";
}
```

If your real `foo` does more work than this example and specialising it would lead to code duplication, you can introduce a helper function which will encapsulate only the `return`/`throw` statements, and specialise that.

Answer (score 5):

In pre-C++17 compiler, you can use tag dispatching to get what you need.

```
template <typename T> tag_t {};

int foo(tag_t<int> t) { return 5; }

std::string foo(tag_t<std::string> t) { return "bar"; }

template<typename T>
T foo() {
    return foo(tag_t<T>());
}
```